# PHP file will not update in browser

Tags: php, browser

For some odd reason, every time I update a file, it is not updating inside a browser (localhost - wampserver). To be more specific. If I have a simple php script:

```
echo "hello world";
```

It runs fine in the browser, and shows the text 'hello world'.

However, if I update it to

```
echo "goodbye world";
```

And refresh the browser, nothing happens. The text remains 'hello world'.

This has not been a problem before and was refreshing perfectly. I tried clearing the browser cache, tested on multiple browsers, restarted my wamp server, and restarted the computer. Nothing seems to be working.

The only way the code seems to be updated is if I run the script from my IDE. Then it shows up in the browser with the updated code. How can this problem be fixed? I want it to go back to the way it was and be able to refresh from within the browser.

Using wampserver php - 5.3.13, apache 2.2.22

Comment: Check if you have installed or enabled any caching mechanism.

Comment: @m4k Tried looking for any type of caching mechanism. Can't find anything. The only thing I installed recently was vmware workstation and I don't think that has anything to do with this.

Comment: @HyunminKim: Make sure you are accessing the edited file itself.

Comment: @mithunsatheesh of course. I save the file as test.php inside a certain directory, and open up the file in the browser under the same directory as test.php.

Comment: Try adding a random query at the end of the url. http://mysite/test.php?rstr=d19n8au9ay

Comment: @bluegman991 still the same result. remains 'hello world'

Comment: Stupid question, are you sure you're saving the fileWhat happens when you save it as a different name?

Comment: @Truth Yes. I'm 100% sure I'm saving the file. I wouldn't have came here to ask this question otherwise. If I just rename the file, it will give me a 404 error. However, if I launch it from my IDE, it shows the same exact path, and it is updated with the contents. From that point on, if I change the contents and just refresh the browser itself, it will not show the changed contents. If I launch the file from my IDE again, it will show changed contents.

Comment: @HyunminKim: I was also having these problems before, you can try disabling caching in apache: http://dabase.com/e/04038/ or in the browser itself but that won't be good if you have a lot of users for the application that you're trying to build. You can also try to clear browser history and try testing again. Don't forget to comment or answer if you found a solution to this weird problem. If any of these suggestions work please let me know. Thanks

Comment: try renameing the file, update browser to get an 404, rename it back, and update browser, do you get new or old content?

Comment: I ended up reinstalling wamp. Seems to work perfectly once again. Thanks for all the input!

Comment: I have this very same problem and it starts out of the blue. I'm using nginx/1.10.3 and php 5.6.33-0+deb8u1.
If rename the PHP file to something else, it works!
`opcache.enable = 0` seems not work with nginx. No idea how to fix this weird situation.

Answer (score 12):

Your script cached in memory with [opcache](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.opcache.php) feature. Disable it in `php.ini`:

```
opcache.enable = 0
```

But you also have to **restart server**. If you use hosting, use control panel to restart or try to change php version to another and revert.

Comment: Or you can set opcache_reset() at head of script.
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.opcache-reset.php

Answer (score 1):

Since this is the first result on Google when searching for this kind of issue, I'd like to add that **if you have opcache enabled, you don't necessarily need to disable it completely**.

You probably have `opcache.validate_timestamps` set to `0` which will stop the automatic update of your files based on the last modification date.

Modify this parameter in your php.ini file:

```
opcache.validate_timestamps = 1
```

Restart the php-fpm service (or apache depending on your situation) and your script should be up to date at the next execution.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to restart the server and also disable your script in php.ini:

```
opcache.enable = 0
```